# In Excel which formula can write that would easily identify if my output condition is true or false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do an excel formula calculated response in regards to comparing the values of three cells.

I have three cells and if one or more cell is populated with a value of greater than "0" I want it to return mix and if false ignore

Comment: Use COUNTIF and IF.

Comment: Care to share some sample data with screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually you're correct you'll need to use COUNTIF or IF. The function IF should be good enough depending on your formula.
Please try to use the formula how I had in illustrated in my image. `=IF(D3>TODAY(),"YES","NO")`, your formula would be different depending on your values or if you're using dates.
If you're not using dates you can still just use IF plus the AND functions like this `"=IF(AND(B3,C3,D3)<="","TRUE","FALSE")"`, see my linked file to see how I did it. Good luck!
Tip, you can check for "0"(a number) or ""(which means blank).

[Check Value in 3 Cells for TRUE-FALSE example in excel.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhFSazYw9XzujXrkjXkpk-VeWJr0)

[Screenshot that might help understand how I use '=IF(AND...' Functions to do just what you originally asked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYipJ.jpg)

To answer the revision to your question I would recommend referencing Microsofts resource on CONCAT function [Combine text and numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-text-and-numbers-a32c8e0e-90a2-435b-8635-5dd2209044ad)

Conversely, I've worked out an example for you. `=IF(E4>0,(CONCAT("YES: B4:D4 ="," ",(TEXT(C4,"MM/DD/YY"))," + ",(TEXT(D4,"MM/DD/YY"))," + ",D4," Total Days")),"NO")` which references my example screen shot here:
[The use of "IF" plus the "CONCAT" function to return the mix of three or more cell values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUiLK.png)